# PHP redirect based on IP AND referrer

Tags: php, regex, redirect, ip, referer

I'm trying to redirect users within my network to a specific landing page on our website based on their IP and a blank referrer. This code works, but it ends up in a redirect loop. How do I break out of the redirect loop to correctly redirect a user? Thanks!

```
$visitor = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$clientip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$ip = a regex list of IPs;
if (empty($visitor))
{
    if (preg_match($ip, $clientip)) {
        header('Location: http://example.com');
            die();
            } 
}
```

Comment: The refer is an optional header. It is a seriously bad idea to assume that it being empty means this is the first time they have visited the site during a session.

Comment: What Quentin said - note also that some proxies and "security suites" will remove this header, whether the user wants them or not (so it's not always a case of "well, the user needs to re-enable it then").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a session to that user that you know that they were redirected already:

```
session_start();
$visitor = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$clientip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$ip = a regex list of IPs;
if (empty($visitor))
{

    //add on if they did not redirect yet.
    if (preg_match($ip, $clientip) && 
        (!isset($_SESSION['redirect']) || !$_SESSION['redirect'])) {
        $_SESSION['redirect'] = true;
        header('Location: http://example.com');
        die();
    } 

}
```

Comment: Curious. Why create server-side files for this? Wouldn't a simple cookie suffice?

Comment: @webbiedave can be eaten, sessions cannot as easily