# how to use header referrer to redirect or allow access to site

Tags: php, javascript, redirect, header

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP redirect based on IP AND referrer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6099535/php-redirect-based-on-ip-and-referrer)

is it possible to redirect a user if they access the site from another location, what i want to do is when the user access the site from google, he will be redirected to the main site, but if he accessed the website from the link that came from the "main site" , a pop up window will appear that contains the restricted site, but since the user came from the "main site" he will be granted access.

any php or javascript will do, as long as it will check if the user came from the main site.

or if possible check from what "IP" the user came from to grant access?

Comment: For what should it be good for that when accessing the site via google that I need to go over the main site to my search target? Also google will likely find out about the practice and not index the pages any longer. You probably should block them in the first place or get into negotiation with google to selectively index your site and provide short summaries for the search index (like news-site do it).

Comment: You can actually put a robots.txt file and have google only index a certain part of your website without any big hassle, google is your friend.

Comment: tried robot.txt my host is 000webhost did not work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redirecting the user can be accomplished using the header() method and setting a "Location: " header for the new target. The conditional can be expressed by evaluating the Referer Header send by the client, this should be available in one of the PHP system variables, see  http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Something along the lines of:

```
if (preg_match("/your-domain/",$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) {
  header('Location: /hidden_page.html');
} else {
  header('Location: /');
}
```

should do the trick.

To redirect the google bot and that actions' implications see [Does Google bot crawl entire site if there is a redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10356749/does-google-bot-crawl-entire-site-if-there-is-a-redirect) and http://forums.digitalpoint.com/showthread.php?t=1210

For figuring out what's inside the variables and how to use regular expressions in PHP, use this example code

```
<pre>
<?php 
    echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']."\n";
    echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."\n";

if (preg_match("/188.174.82.97/",$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) {
        echo "Yes";
    } else {
        echo "No";
    }
?>
</pre>
```

in your script or something like phpfiddle.org

Comment: English maybe? http://php.net/manual/de/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: @telexper Thanks, I was auto redirected - it's fixed now.

Comment: IP checking can be done using $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].

Comment: is this possible? (preg_match("domain.com/*",$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] |"subdomain.domain.com/*",$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])

Comment: (preg_match("52.192.84.556",$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) like this?

Comment: Look up the documentation for preg_match, any string matching will do but your syntax is flawed. preg_match should naturally match substrings. Also, I will extend the post one last time.

Comment: and also does this work for a pop up window?

Comment: I've added more info for your, I think this should absolutely be a sufficient starting point and you can figure out the details for your application from here.

Answer (score 0):

check $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] variable in a conditional to see what the user's referrer actually is and then use header() method to actually redirect to another URL.